# Site config exclude relative path for few pages

Tags: urls, url-rewrite

I have my site definition like below:

```
<site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        name="mysite"
        hostName="mysite.com"
        scheme="https"
        notFoundItem="not-found"
        enableTracking="true"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/mysite"
        startItem="/home"
        virtualFolder="myrelateivepath"
        physicalFolder="/website"
        targetHostName="mysite"
        database="web"
        domain="mydomain"
        allowDebug="true"
        cacheHtml="false"
        filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB"
        enablePreview="true"
        enableWebEdit="true"
        enableDebugger="true"
        disableClientData="false"/>
```

and I've set up URL rewrite to include virtualFolder path(i.e "myrelateivepath" in above config) for all pages that are under this site.

now business is asking me to exclude virtualFolder path in the URLs for few of the pages. Any workaround to do this?

Comment: There is no any OOTB functionality available for this, but you can do it by creating custom Link provider and Custom Item Resolver.

Comment: You should be able to update the current URL rewrite to add some exceptions. Can you please update your answer with the current URL rewrite which you have setup?